# OnClick before Submit. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The thing I'm trying to do is to change the value inside an `<input>` field.
The idea is that when a customer clicks on one of 3 buttons inside the form the
`LIST_ID` will change before the submission to a `LIST_ID_1` or `2` or `3`, corresponding to the clicked button. As a result when the form is submit the `id` would be changed depending on what button was clicked.

```
<input type="hidden" name="g" id="hidden_field" value="LIST_ID">
```

Here is something I've tried:

```
$('#subscription_form').submit(function() {
    jQuery(':button').click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'Button_1') {
            /*Action;*/
            $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_1");    
        }
        else if (this.id == 'Button_2') {
            /*Action;*/
            $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_2");
        }
        else if (this.id == 'Button_3') {
            /*Action;*/
            $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_3");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="//manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/subscribe" method="POST" id="subscription_form" novalidate="novalidate" class="klaviyo_subscription_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="g" id="hidden_field" value="LIST_ID">
    <div class="klaviyo_fieldset">
        <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
            <label for="LIST_ID_$email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" id="LIST_ID_$email" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="klaviyo_form_actions">
        <button type="submit" id="Button_1" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
            <span>Button_1</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="Button_1" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
            <span>Button_2</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="Button_3" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
            <span>Button_3</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="klaviyo_below_submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: how do you want onclick before submit if you have `.click()` inside `.submit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you only attach the click event after the form has been submit. Unless the user double clicks a button (once to submit the form and attach the click handler, and another time to actually fire the click handler) it won't work. You need to place the `click()` handler outside of the `submit()`, like this:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'Button_1') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_1");    
    }
    else if (this.id == 'Button_2') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_2");
    }
    else if (this.id == 'Button_3') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_3");
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nzbsrexc/)

However it should be noted that it's better practice to hook to the `submit()` event of the `form`. In that case, to get the submit button which was clicked you would need to use `document.activeElement` like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var $btn = $(document.activeElement);
    if ($btn.prop('id') == 'Button_1') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_1");    
    }
    else if ($btn.prop('id') == 'Button_2') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_2");
    }
    else if ($btn.prop('id') == 'Button_3') {
        $("#hidden_field").val("LIST_ID_3");
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nzbsrexc/1/)

Finally, you should look at using DRY principles to make your code both shorter and easier to maintain. To do that you can use a `data-*` attribute on the buttons themselves, like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="Button_1" data-list="LIST_ID_1" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
    <span>Button_1</span>
</button>
<button type="submit" id="Button_2" data-list="LIST_ID_2" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
    <span>Button_2</span>
</button>
<button type="submit" id="Button_3" data-list="LIST_ID_3" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
    <span>Button_3</span>
</button>
```

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
    var listId = $(document.activeElement).data('list');
    $("#hidden_field").val(listId);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nzbsrexc/2/)

Comment: Just wondering... is it possible that the form will be submitted before the hidden field gets updated? Wouldn't it be wise to first prevent the submission, then change the hidden field, and first then submit it?

Comment: When using a `click()` event on the button, yes it is. However with something as simple as retrieving a property from another element it should be fine in this case. I have provided a couple of alternatives for using the `submit` event of the form, which is better practice anyway.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan greatly appreciate for your help. 
I don't know why, but the first example is not working...
But the last one is doing greate. 
Thank you!